# Problems setting view for header in a grouped table

Tags: ios, css, header

I'm trying to customize the headers for sections in a grouped table. The view I set for the first section in table looks fine, but subsequent section headers look like cropped at top and at bottom (in this screenshot it is only shown at top):

[image: iPhone_groupedTable_header]

I've been trying different X and Y values for `frame.size.origin`, but it remains looking the same. This is my code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 1) {
          UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 70)];
          [wrapper setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

          UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 20)];
          label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Section 2 Header", @"");
          [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
          [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

          [wrapper addSubview:label];

          return wrapper;
   }

   else
          return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 1)
          return 70;
   else
          return 0;
}
```

I do the same for all the section headers, and only the first one is correctly displayed, what could I'm doing wrong? Regarding this issue, is it possible to dynamically know the height of an `UILabel` will take once its text and font size are known, or should you always set its frame size "at a guess"? The same for the height of view for the header that is set in `heightForHeaderInSection:` method.

Thanks!

Comment: After setting up the label, call `[label sizeToFit];`. This will ensure the label's frame properly fits the text. You might need to update the label's origin after that.

Comment: Your code only for first section. If you need to all sections you should delete in your method `if (section == 1)` or provide `if (section == 2)` and etc.. Hope it help. Or you can call `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {` and insert height for footer.

Comment: @user2545330 I omitted the code for the rest of sections here because it is quite similar and I didn't want to paste a very long code snippet

Comment: @rmaddy Is there any way to set something like `headerView.frame.size.height` in `heightForHeaderInSection:`, or have you to supply a fixed value as I currently do? It looks like `heightForHeaderInSection:` method is called before `viewForHeaderInSection:` method, but what if you don´t know at this point what the height of a label in a header will have?

Comment: @AppsDev Use: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30.0f;
}`

Answer (score 0):

you have not set height for header for the sections other than section 1 in this code,you should remove if(section==1) condition and provide common height for each section and then check

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 1)
          return 70;
   else
          return 0;
}
```

thanks,
Mittal.